# How do I delete BOTH lines of a duplicate pair in a text file in bash?

Tags: command-line, text-editing, duplicate, parsing

I want to delete both lines of a duplicate pair in a text file.

There is no way to do this using `sort -u file` or `awk '!a[$0]++' file` which both delete duplicated lines.

Somehow I would have to capture the deleted lines and run `sed` to use this list and then delete the already deleted (is there some way to get this output?). The pattern of the duplicated lines is not predictable.

I am looking for a shorter way than writing a complete bash program. It seems like a useful tool and there should be an easy way to do it.

Easy to delete one of the duplicates. I need to delete *both* and can't find a way to do it. Encountered during parsing.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is it necessary to maintain the order of the lines?

Comment: Yes I need to maintain order

Comment: How large is the file; does it fit in memory?

Comment: Not a large file.  10-200 lines of ascii text

Comment: I voted to reopen. If the file is not very large then something like `awk '{a[$0]++; 1} END {for (line in a) if (a[line] == 1) print line}'` may be a good start.

Comment: Thanks...  redid script so I don't need to do this!  Found a better way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-u` command-line argument to the `uniq` utility, which does precisely what you want:

```
−u   Suppress the writing of lines
     that are repeated in the
     input.
```

You still need to sort the input, of course:

```
sort file | uniq -u
```